# Atmega328P и rs232-serial переходник на базе ch340g

Tags: usb, arduino, avr, rs232

Безуспешно пытаюсь подключить atmega232 к компьютеру по юсб при помощи самодельного переходника на базе микросхемы ch340g.

Ссылка на схему переходника: http://www.avrfreaks.net/sites/default/files/ch340gLeds.png

Ссылка на скетч для контроллера: https://pastebin.com/av9uJRee

Скетч прост - отправляешь символ по ком-порту на устройство и получаешь от него этот же символ.

Когда я заливаю скетч в ардуино и подключаю ее через переходник, все работает. Когда заливаю скетч в атмегу, то компьютер определяет устройство, открывает ком-порт (типа все идет нормально), но посылаемые символы канут в неизвестность.
Я специально проверял на ардуинке, чтобы выявить, где проблема, но скетч и переходник рабочие. Фьюзы на контроллере не залочены.

Я новичок, и эта задача поставила меня в тупик - не знаю даже, в какую сторону копать, чтобы разобраться.

Подскажите, в чем здесь может быть проблема?

Update:
С помощью отладочного диода было выяснено, что скетч в атмеге работает: по приходу данных вызывается прерывание (где по задумке данные должны сохранятся и отправляться обратно), однако атмега не понимает, что за данные ей пришли. Т.е. условие "если прислали "r" зажги диод не срабатывает (на ардуинке срабатывает).
Посмотрел на то, что происходит, с помощью pySerial: после посылки любых данных атмега шлет ноль (ниче особо нового).
Буду благодарен, если подскажете куда копать/как гуглить в связи со сложившейся ситуацией.

Comment: Может вы не к тем пинам переходник подключаете?

Comment: Так у Вас же трансмиттер не разрешён. Вот данные в комп и не отправляются.